# python list literal / initialization with dynamic number of elements

Tags: python

I have the following list initialization in a test script of mine:

```
newSequenceCore=["ls", "ns", "*", "cm", "*", "ov", "ov", "ov", "ov", "kd"]
```

(standing for a sequence of commands to be entered at a console application).

Is there an idiomatic way to dynamically control the number of "ov" elements in the list? (i.e. without having to create a function taking the number of "ov" elements as a parameter that returns the list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the multiply operator for this.

```
>>> ['ov'] * 4
['ov', 'ov', 'ov', 'ov']

>>> ["ls", "ns", "*", "cm", "*"] + ["ov"] * 4 + ["kd"]
['ls', 'ns', '*', 'cm', '*', 'ov', 'ov', 'ov', 'ov', 'kd']
>>>
```

Fun note: You can also do this with strings:

```
>>> '-' * 15
'---------------'
```